# How do I add items to the Finder context menu in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, contextmenu

I'm in the process of porting a Windows application to OS X (we wrote it in Java so most of the code is portable), but what I'm currently unsure of is how to add context menu items in the Finder window when the user right clicks on an item (i.e. I wish to add some items to the  the menu that has "Open" "Open with" , "Get Info", etc... when the user right clicks).

Most of the articles I've found deal specifically with Windows (I've searched for "context menus" and "shell extension", but I believe I may be searching the wrong terms), so I'm curious as to how to go about adding this in Mac or what literature I should be reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to take a look at using [Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html). The Finder appends applicable Services to the end of its contextual menu and, depending on your needs, just fit the bill.

Comment: link doesn't work any more, any updated answer for this requirement?

Comment: Looks like the link has changed to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In each Library folder may be a "Contextual Menu Items" folder.  Special plugin bundles placed in that folder will be loaded and may place items in contextual menus.  Look in `Menus.h` for the entry points of these plugin bundles.

```
CMPluginExamineContext
CMPluginHandleSelection
CMPluginPostMenuCleanup
```

From what I have read, Contextual Menu Items are not supported for 64 bit applications.  As of 10.6 most Apple applications, including the Finder, run in 64 bit when available.

There are third party applications that restore contextual menu items on 10.6 if you must have them.